# JavaScript:How to convert jpeg image tag to raw binary file?

Tags: javascript, image, binary, base64

Here is the piece of my code that i tried;

```
<img src= "hello.jpg">
var binary = atob(base64.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(binary);
```

But it doesn't work as expected.
How can I transform the tag to a binary

Is there any alternative way to convert the image tag into binary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 canvas or use FileReader() here is the example for both:

```js
function convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null;
  };
  img.src = url;
}

function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}

$('#img2b64').submit(function(event) {
  var imageUrl = $(this).find('[name=url]').val();
  var convertType = $(this).find('[name=convertType]').val();
  var convertFunction = convertType === 'FileReader' ?
    convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader :
    convertImgToDataURLviaCanvas;

  convertFunction(imageUrl, function(base64Img) {
    $('.output')
      .find('.textbox')
      .val(base64Img)
      .end()
      .find('.link')
      .attr('href', base64Img)
      .text(base64Img)
      .end()
      .find('.img')
      .attr('src', base64Img)
      .end()
      .find('.size')
      .text(base64Img.length)
      .end()
      .find('.convertType')
      .text(convertType)
      .end()
      .show()
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="img2b64">
  <h2>Input</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Convert via:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" name="convertType">
        <option value="Canvas" selected>Canvas</option>
        <option value="FileReader">FileReader</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">URL:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert an IMAGE-URL" value="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png" required />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="output form-horizontal" style="display: none">
  <hr>
  <h2>Output</h2>
  <div>
    <strong class="col-sm-2 text-right">Converted via:</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <span class="convertType"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong class="col-sm-2 text-right">Size:</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <span class="size"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong class="col-sm-2 text-right">Text:</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control textbox"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong class="col-sm-2 text-right">Link:</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <a href="#" class="link"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <strong class="col-sm-2 text-right">Image:</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <img class="img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```